Help Needed: Resolving "EIP2612: Invalid Signature"
I am encountering an error message "EIP2612: invalid signature" when testing the permit function in my contract.
This is my contract:
// @inheritdoc IPayments
contract Payments is IPayments {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    // @inheritdoc IPayments
    function subsidizedTransferToken(
        TransferIntent calldata _intent,
        EIP2612SignatureTransferData calldata _signatureTransferData
    ) external override {
        uint256 neededAmount = _intent.recipientAmount;

        // Permit this contract to spend the payer's tokens
        IERC2612 erc20Permit = IERC2612(_intent.recipientCurrency);
        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = splitSignature(_signatureTransferData.signature);
        erc20Permit.permit(_signatureTransferData.owner, address(this), neededAmount, _intent.deadline, v, r, s);

        // Transfer tokens
        IERC20(_intent.recipientCurrency).safeTransferFrom(_signatureTransferData.owner, _intent.recipient, neededAmount);
    }

    function splitSignature(bytes calldata sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (
            uint8 v,
            bytes32 r,
            bytes32 s
        )
    {
        require(sig.length == 65, "InvalidEIP2612Signature");

        assembly {
            r := calldataload(sig.offset)
            s := calldataload(add(sig.offset, 32))
            v := byte(0, calldataload(add(sig.offset, 64)))
        }
    }
}

However, when I test the permit function outside of the contract with the same values, it works fine.
Below is the code I am using for testing:
export async function getPermit(chain, accountAddress, token, amount) {
  const [domain, nonce] = await Promise.all([
    getPermitDomain(token),
    readContractProperty(token.address, 'nonces', [accountAddress])
  ]);

  const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 86400;
  const signature = await signTypedData(Wagmi.config, {
    domain: domain,
    types: {
      Permit: [
        { name: "owner", type: "address" },
        { name: "spender", type: "address" },
        { name: "value", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "nonce", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "deadline", type: "uint256" },
      ],
    },
    primaryType: 'Permit',
    message: {
      owner: accountAddress,
      spender: chain.contract_address,
      value: amount.toString(),
      nonce: nonce.toString(),
      deadline,
    },
  });

  const { v, r, s } = hexToSignature(signature);

  console.log(r);
  console.log(s);
  console.log(Number(v));

  const request = await prepareTransactionRequest(Wagmi.config, {
    address: token.address,
    abi: IERC20_2612_ABI,
    functionName: 'permit',
    args: [accountAddress, chain.contract_address, amount, deadline, Number(v), r, s],
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: 1000000000n,
    gas: 5000000,
  });

  const hash = await writeContract(Wagmi.config, { ...request, __mode: 'prepared' });
  const receipt = await waitForTransactionReceipt(Wagmi.config, { hash, confirmation: 12 });
  console.log(receipt);

  const allowance = await getTokenAllowance(token.address, chain.contract_address, accountAddress);
  console.log(`Check allowance of tokenReceiver: ${allowance} - ${amount}`);

  return {
    owner: accountAddress,
    signature: signature
  };
}

Could you help identify why the signature is invalid ?
https://dashboard.tenderly.co/explorer/vnet/e21441a0-4848-443d-a5bf-b2323bb02df1/tx/0x190ad7295304f7bbac915fdcede3a19b5069813aabb4d8942298025544dd7ec9

You're facing that error because the owner address that you've used while generating the signature off-chain is not matching with the _signatureTransferData.owner value that you're passing as the first argument while calling the erc20Permit.permit() on-chain.
NOTE: In your case, with the signature that you've generated off-chain, you've already signed and sent the transaction when you've executed the writeContract() function for calling permit() in your application, which is basically updating the nonce and therefore isn't allowing you to use the same signature when you're passing that in the contract function directly.
So, you need to separate the off-chain signature generation from the sending of transaction logic. Basically, you can do that by commenting out the relevant code for sending the transaction, like:
export async function getPermit(chain, accountAddress, token, amount) {
    const [domain, nonce] = await Promise.all([
        getPermitDomain(token),
        readContractProperty(token.address, 'nonces', [accountAddress])
    ]);

    const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 86400;
    const signature = await signTypedData(Wagmi.config, {
        domain: domain,
        types: {
            Permit: [
                { name: "owner", type: "address" },
                { name: "spender", type: "address" },
                { name: "value", type: "uint256" },
                { name: "nonce", type: "uint256" },
                { name: "deadline", type: "uint256" },
            ],
        },
        primaryType: 'Permit',
        message: {
            owner: accountAddress,
            spender: chain.contract_address,
            value: amount.toString(),
            nonce: nonce.toString(),
            deadline,
        },
    });

    console.log("Signature:", signature);

    // const { v, r, s } = hexToSignature(signature);

    // console.log(r);
    // console.log(s);
    // console.log(Number(v));

    // const request = await prepareTransactionRequest(Wagmi.config, {
    //     address: token.address,
    //     abi: IERC20_2612_ABI,
    //     functionName: 'permit',
    //     args: [accountAddress, chain.contract_address, amount, deadline, Number(v), r, s],
    //     maxPriorityFeePerGas: 1000000000n,
    //     gas: 5000000,
    // });

    // const hash = await writeContract(Wagmi.config, { ...request, __mode: 'prepared' });
    // const receipt = await waitForTransactionReceipt(Wagmi.config, { hash, confirmation: 12 });
    // console.log(receipt);

    // const allowance = await getTokenAllowance(token.address, chain.contract_address, accountAddress);
    // console.log(`Check allowance of tokenReceiver: ${allowance} - ${amount}`);

    return {
        owner: accountAddress,
        signature: signature
    };
}

Now, you can just grab the signature value and use the same while calling the subsidizedTransferToken() function of your contract.

Here's the minimal example that I've created for generating off-chain signature and then passing the same along with the corresponding values on-chain while calling the permit() function:
Generating the Signature Off-Chain (using ethers.js v5.7.2)
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

// Example data
const tokenAddress = "ERC20_PERMIT_TOKEN_ADDRESS";
const owner = "OWNER_ADDRESS";
const spender = "SPENDER_ADDRESS";
const value = ethers.utils.parseUnits("AMOUNT_TO_BE_PERMITTED", 18); // Adjust decimals as per token
const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 86400; // 1 day

// Provider setup (using a testnet or local node)
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("JSON_RPC_URL");

// Signer's private key
const privateKey = "OWNER_PRIVATE_KEY";
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

// Get the token contract instance
const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(
    tokenAddress,
    [
        "function name() public view returns (string)",
        "function nonces(address owner) public view returns (uint256)",
        "function DOMAIN_SEPARATOR() external view returns (bytes32)"
    ],
    wallet
);

// Generate the permit signature
async function getPermitSignature() {
    const name = await tokenContract.name();
    const nonce = await tokenContract.nonces(owner);
    // const domainSeparator = await tokenContract.DOMAIN_SEPARATOR();

    const permitData = {
        owner: owner,
        spender: spender,
        value: value,
        nonce: nonce,
        deadline: deadline
    };

    const domain = {
        name: name,
        version: "1",
        chainId: parseInt((await provider.getNetwork()).chainId.toString()), // Adjust for your network
        verifyingContract: tokenAddress
    };

    const types = {
        Permit: [
            { name: "owner", type: "address" },
            { name: "spender", type: "address" },
            { name: "value", type: "uint256" },
            { name: "nonce", type: "uint256" },
            { name: "deadline", type: "uint256" }
        ]
    };

    const signature = await wallet._signTypedData(domain, types, permitData);

    console.log("ERC20 Permit Token:", tokenAddress);
    console.log("Owner:", owner);
    console.log("Spender:", spender);
    console.log("Amount:", value.toString());
    console.log("Deadline:", deadline);
    console.log("Signature:", signature);

    return signature;
}

getPermitSignature();

Using the Permit Signature On-Chain
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/interfaces/IERC2612.sol";

contract TestPermit {
    function setPermit(
        address erc20PermitToken,
        address owner,
        address spender,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 deadline,
        bytes calldata signature
    ) external {
        IERC2612 erc20Permit = IERC2612(erc20PermitToken);
        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = splitSignature(signature);
        erc20Permit.permit(owner, spender, amount, deadline, v, r, s);
    }

    function splitSignature(bytes calldata sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (
            uint8 v,
            bytes32 r,
            bytes32 s
        )
    {
        require(sig.length == 65, "InvalidEIP2612Signature");

        assembly {
            r := calldataload(sig.offset)
            s := calldataload(add(sig.offset, 32))
            v := byte(0, calldataload(add(sig.offset, 64)))
        }
    }
}


its matching. its same address

Make sure that the other details like permitTokenAddress, spender, amount, deadline, nonce match too.

Also, you can test the minimal example that I've provided, in order to understand the workflow better.

Please check the information that I've just added as a NOTE in my answer.
